# How do I change the voice/cutscene language?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I have the Spanish PAL version of the game. Is there a way to play with the English NTSC voices on the cutscenes and pursuits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need an NTSC copy of the game. I can't leave any links, but a Google search should do the job. After getting an NTSC English copy, you need to copy 2 folders.

Make sure that it is a NTSC-US copy by going into the "MOVIES" folder and find the files that have "english_ntsc" on it's name:

[image: MOVIES folder]

To save the old ones just in case, rename the folders to something else. I renamed "MOVIES" to "MOVIES_PAL" and "SPEECH" to "SPEECH_PAL".

Please note that the folder "SPEECH" is in "SOUND".

[image: Renaming the MOVIES folder to MOVIES_PAL]

[image: Renaming the SPEECH folder to SPEECH_PAL]

Copy the "MOVIES" folder from the NTSC copy to the PAL one.

[image: Adding the English MOVIES]

Then, open the "SOUND" folder and copy the "SPEECH" folder.

[image: Adding the English SOUND/SPEECH]

Here comes the dangerous step: open the Registry Editor (press WIN+R, write regedit.exe and press ENTER/RETURN).

[image: The Registry Editor ready to be opened]

On the left side of the window, navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted":

[image: The Registry key]

**NOTE**: If you installed "Need for Speed Most Wanted 2012" there will also be *Need for Speed(TM) Most Wanted*, **ignore that registry key and select the one without "(TM)"**.

On the right side, right click "Region" and select "Delete" or "Remove":

[image: Deleting "Region"]

You are now ready to use NFS Most Wanted with the English voices on your current text language. If you want to use a different text language, double click "Language" and write your language name, then double click "Locale" and write your language ID.

This is a table with the Language and it's corresponding Locale:

- Chinese / zh
- Danish / da
- Dutch / nl
- English US / en
- Finnish / fi
- French / fr
- German / de
- Italian / it
- Korean / ko
- Polish / pl
- Spanish / es
- Swedish / sv